# asp.net mvc 2 ajax.googleapis.co ofline

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

My asp.net mvc application uses files ....

http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js

http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.5/jquery-ui.min.js

Can these be downloaded to files given radial applications for offline mode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right click the links, then save the files. Update your script reference to point to these new saved files.

You could also put in some javascript code to detect if jquery has been loaded from the online version, and if not, then reference the offline versions.

**EDIT**

```
 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="js/libs/jquery-1.6.2.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
```

Comment: thank you an answer!
How to write js code to detect where the file is loaded?